# Getting dfsutil for current versions Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, replication

`dfsutil` is useful on workstations for checking what's going on with the DFS shares that the client is subscribed to, e.g. by running `dfsutil /pktinfo`.

For Windows 10 pre-October 2018 `dfsutil` can be downloaded as part of [RSAT Tools for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=45520), but how do I get `dfsutil` for current versions of Windows 10?

Comment: It's worth noting that right-clicking on a share, selecting 'Properties' and looking at the DFS tab is a much more cheap-and-cheerful option to get some useful information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [RSAT Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=45520) download page gives a link to the [list of RSAT tools available via Features on Demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-non-language-fod#remote-server-administration-tools-rsat) in newer versions of Windows 10, however there are about 20 different RSAT features which you can download, and nothing in that page clearly says which one you need for `dfsutil`.

So, the full answer is:

- Open Windows 10 settings
- Search for 'Manage optional features'
- Click on 'Add a feature'
- Choose the package '**RSAT: File Services Tools**' and click 'Install'
- Depending on the precise version of Windows 10, you will either see the package installing immediately, or if not you will need to click back once to see installation progress
- Wait to see the package finish installing

That's it, `dfsutil` is now available from Command Prompt and PowerShell; no reboot is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the optional feature with this PowerShell (admin) command:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Rsat.FileServices.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0"
```

This will install dfsutil and also the DFS management console (dfsmgmt.msc)

Comment: That's a useful answer, thanks! What is the meaning of the number at the end of the string, `~~~~0.0.1.0`? From a quick Google all the examples seem to include it, but from a quick test the command seems to run fine without it, `Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "Rsat.FileServices.Tools"`.